# Are calendar Ids and event Ids in Microsoft Graph globally unique or just unique per mailbox/user?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

My application deals with multi-user, multi-tenant Microsoft Graph calendar data and I need to keep a record of unique calendars and events.

I can't find very detailed information on this in the documentation. It does say the Ids are unique per user/mailbox (for calendar) and per calendar (for event Ids), and obviously they have to be.

But if the user and tenant boundary is crossed, can I assume each calendar Id and event Id I obtain from any user in any tenant via Microsoft graph is unique, so I won't encounter two different calendars/events with the same Ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they should be unique in the world see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtagentryid-canonical-property . Basically the Id used by the Graph (and EWS) contains the PidTagEntryId along with various routing flags and info but that underlying id should always mean they are unique. However be careful with the ical uid which won't be unique